# 404 on all .html URLs

Tags: url, development, 404, product-urls

I am getting an nginx 404 on all pages ending in .html in my test instance, which is in a subdirectory at the root of production. For instance, /test/, /test/contact/ and /test/about-us/ are all good. But /test/women.html, /test/solar-jacket.html, and /test/men.html all return 404. So, no category or product pages. :-( It's the same issue with or without rewrites.

This issue is only on my default store. A second store running on a subdomain has no problem displaying the same product pages.

Edit: It's a problem with ".html". If I enter a bad URL without ".html", I get a Magento 404. All URLs that end with ".html" return nginx 404.

Comment: try to disable url_rewrite and then flush cache. Hope it will work.

Comment: Same issue with or without rewrites.

Comment: Do you have a folder in your project root named "test"?

Comment: what happens when you disable html suffixes?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema Yes, my testing instance is in a folder in root named "test" with an exact copy of root.

Comment: @ToonVanDooren That fixes it! I don't know why. It works with .html on my local test instance but not on the production server. Do you have any idea why? My live site uses .html suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.html` suffix from using admin panel.

Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog**

In *Search Engine Optimisation Section*:

Remove the value from text-field inside Product URL Suffix. Do the same for category view.

Re-index the site and clean the cache:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```